# Displaying abbreviation names of authors

Tags: bibtex

I would like to cite authors just "usually", like [Author, Year].

For example:
alea iacta est. [Caesar, 2013]

What I get is:
alea iacta est. [Cae13]

Although I am using a .bib file with the following information:

```
@TECHREPORT{caesar2013,
   AUTHOR="G. I. Caesar",
   TITLE="Title",
   INSTITUTION="RomeDome",
   TYPE="misc",
   MONTH=jan,
   YEAR=2013
}
```

However, the information is correct in the bibliography. Is there any way to change that? There shouldn't be a problem with my compiler or properties, because I am using the online editor and compiler writelatex.com. Is there any \usepackage tag or another option to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example? I believe you're using the `abbrv` BibTeX style, while you should be using the `natbib` package and the `plainnat` BibTeX style.

Comment: I am sorry, I completely forgot to attach the screenshot I made. Here it is: http://abload.de/img/citesasbk.png

Comment: You Sir, are a genius. I am using \bibliographystyle{plainnat} now and it almost works. It looks like [Dijck(2013)] now, but it should be like: [Dijck, 2013]. Any more hints for that? Thank you a lot in advance! EDIT: The \bibliographystyle{apalike} did it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Remarks

Looks like you're searching for either the `apalike` or `plainnat` style provided by `natbib`.

## `apalike`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@TECHREPORT{caesar2013,
  AUTHOR="G. I. Caesar",
  TITLE="Title",
  INSTITUTION="RomeDome",
  TYPE="misc",
  MONTH=jan,
  YEAR=2013
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\citep{caesar2013}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

## `plainnat`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@TECHREPORT{caesar2013,
  AUTHOR="G. I. Caesar",
  TITLE="Title",
  INSTITUTION="RomeDome",
  TYPE="misc",
  MONTH=jan,
  YEAR=2013
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\citep{caesar2013}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

## Output

In this case the output is the same for both styles.

> [image]

Comment: Thank you a lot, \bibliographystyle{apalike} did it! (while plainnat does make a difference for me, because I'd get [Caesar(2013)] with that.